# How to pass dynamic data to child component in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component and i have to pass data to child once i will receive response in parent component.

> **Challenges**
>
> 1) I have to wait to pass data till i will receive Response in Parent Component.
>
> 2) I want to execute particular function in Child Component once I will receive data from child.

**Parent.component.ts**

```
JSON.parse(this.responseData, (key, value) => {
 if (key === 'patient-list') {
      this.mrn = this.totalPatientList[0]['value']['patientmrn'];
}
});
```

**Parent.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Child.component.html**

```
@Input() patientdata:any;


ngAfterViewChecked(){
console.log('Data Received -----', this.patientdata);    
}
```

I hope I am able to explain my problem to you all.

Comment: instead <router-outer> i can call child component in Parent <patient-info [patientdata]="passData"></patient-info>

Answer (score 2):

There is no child/parent communication in your example as it requires a component to be directly in the parent component.html.

You need to rely on guard resolver to be able to load 'Child' upon data reception.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [Services](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) to pass data between multiple components.
2. To pass data after processing return an [Observer](http://www.mukeshkumar.net/articles/angular5/share-data-between-sibling-components-in-angular-5-using-rxjs-behaviorsubject) instead of data, and the other component will be notified once the data is returned properly.

Answer (score 2):

you are using routing, maybe the best way is use a singleton service for the communication of the two components.

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers are sensible, and will work cleanly.

An alternative would be to use [@ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/store) to manage state & enable a uni-directional flow of data to your components.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problem to pass dynamic data from parent to child, searched all over but did not get any help. Finally i tried this one and it superbly worked for me. Try this one, it might help you.

child component:

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() title: string;

  //rest code goes here...
}
```

parent component:

```
export class ParentComponent {
        headerTitle: string = '';

        //rest code ...
//on click changing the value
        onHeaderChange() {
            this.headerTitle = "MyHeader";
        }
    }
```

in parent component html file place code like below with single quote

```
<child-component [title]='headerTitle'></child-component>
```